# React.cloneElement vs render props pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm learning React and trying to figure out the best way to dynamically add props. I know two approaches how to do that, but cannot understand which one is better and faster.

First way is to use React.cloneElement api

```js
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const child = React.cloneElement(children, { newProp: 'some new prop' });

  return child;
};

const Child = ({ newProp }) => <div>{newProp}</div>;

const App = () => (
  <Parent>
    <Child />
  </Parent>
);
```

The second way is to use "render props" pattern, described on official React site: [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

```js
const Parent = ({ render }) => {
  const newProp = 'some new prop';

  return render(newProp);
}

const Child = ({ newProp }) => <div>{newProp}</div>;

const App = () => (
  <Parent render={props => <Child newProp={props} />} />
);
```

Both approaches give same results, but I don't know what is going on under the hood and which way to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`React.cloneElement` is a helper that's usually used to pass `inline-props` to avoid polluted codes. Instead of passing a prop down like this:

```
return <Child propA={myProps.propA} propB={myProps.propB} />
```

You can do this:

```
return React.cloneElement(Child, {...myProps})
```

Which is almost the same as:

```
 return <Child {...myProps} />
```

The only difference here is that `cloneElement` will preserve previously attached `refs`.

Now `renderProps` is a technique to `reuse stateful logic` and has different applications than `cloneElement`. The first will help you with `props` manipulation, the second is an equivalent to `High Order Components` and is used whenever you want to reuse some logic to dinamically inject props into your children:

```
class Animation extends Component{
   state = {} 
   componentDidMount(){/*...*/}
   componentDidUpdate(){/*...*/}

   render(){
       const { customProps } = this.state
       const { children } = this.props

       return children(customProps)
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example on `cloneElement` is misleading. It should reflect what the [documentation shows](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), mostly that you pass an `element` to `cloneElement` and that it's equivalent to using the `<element.type {...element.props} {...props} />`.

Comment: also, `React.cloneElement(Child, myProps)` is enough, no need to spread a new object unless you're going to add new props to it.

Comment: I can also use `cloneElement` to _reuse stateful logic_. My `Parent` component in the example can have state like in your one and pass it to cloned child element as props. Isn't it right?

Comment: Sure! It's just not as convenient but will work as well.

Comment: So there is no performance or memory difference, it is just like "style"? And `cloneElement` is not the preferred one.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in use `cloneElement` to perform the prop injection, but the logic wrapped still needs to be inside an `HOC` or `renderProps` component. In terms of performance there is no difference between `cloneElement(Child, props)` and `<Child {...props}/>`